# Nodemailer - "error":"TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'to' of object '#<Object>'"

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, nodemailer

I tried everything but nothing works.
Everything ends up in the same place.

"typescript": "^4.6.2"
node version: v16.14.2

Comment: Please do not post images of code. Copy-paste it into your post.

Comment: Ok, sorry bout that

Comment: (You can edit your post with the code.)